# Don't work ssh in a VM Centos

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, centos6.5

When I tried to connect my Ubuntu 13.10 to my VM Centos 6.5 using ssh appear the message "Connection refused" or "No route to host" even than I change the port, noting change.

[image: see here]

I need to use SSH, VPN and Samba, but this IP in my VM Centos do not work.

How Can I resolve this problem?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How can I connect in my VM Centos using ssh?

Comment: Please, unhold my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your guest OS (the CentOS VM) does not have an IP independent of the host OS (Ubuntu). If you want to ssh into the guest, you will need to set up either NAT networking or a bridged network interface in your hypervisor.

Comment: Ok but my vm centos is already on a bridged network interface see here [link](http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/captura_de_tela_de_2014-04-03_19_18_12-png/mostrar-codigo) And is not work my ssh

Comment: is the ssh daemon running on centos?

Comment: I don't know. how can I discover if I use a ssh daemon?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem to restart sshd in my centos.

[See here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#head-9c01429983dccbf74ade8674815980dc6434d3ba)

Just this...